# how can we create new apache isis project in eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, isis

Hey i am new in APACHE ISIS. I am creating small application with making changes in ISIS demo application. can anyone tell me how to create new ISIS project in eclipse IDE?

Comment: I've edited your tags to remove Isis2, which is a tag for isis2.codeplex.com and not related to the Apache project.

Comment: I edited your tags to remove wicket and shiro as Apache Isis can be used with both of them but isn't related.

Comment: Do you know how to use Maven?

Comment: Ken Birman: could you create a tag for Isis?  I don't have enough rep on SO to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As "his" says in his comment, you need to use Maven.

Per our website:

http://isis.apache.org/getting-started/quickstart-archetype.html

and

http://isis.apache.org/getting-started/screencasts.html

Comment: Thanx DAN and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ISIS-299 this issue is resolved or not?

Comment: It is possible to logout, it's just that we implement it in rather a crude fashion at the moment.  That issue is to improve the implementation and make things cleaner.

Comment: After hosting my isis application in Apache Tomcate 7 and i used my username and password for login, that is already put on shiro.ini file this problem occure.. After clearing my browser cookies then i redirect to login page.